# How to get Present/Last Data (without initializing) NetBeans?

Tags: java

Note: I have this problem and solved by C# in Unity3D (without a database).

## Problem Overview

In NetBeans (Java), I have a form like this:

[image: form input|report and form report]

I want 'the report' from Report Form just like 'the report' from InputData From

I create 2 form class and 1 java class.

**"mainCode" JavaClass**

```
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String address;
```

And of course with Setter and Getter

**"InputData" JavaFORMClass**

```
    mainCode mainCode = new mainCode();
    LookData lookData = new LookData();

    String name;
    int age;
    String address;
    /**
     * Creates new form InputData
     */
    public InputData() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void setData(){
        mainCode.setName(jTextField1.getText());
        mainCode.setAge(Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText()));
        mainCode.setAddress(jTextArea1.getText());
    }

    public void getData(){
        name = mainCode.getName();
        age = mainCode.getAge();
        address = mainCode.getAddress();
    }

    public void printData(){
        String data = null;
        data =  "BIODATA REPORT \n"
                + "Your Name    : "+name+"\n"
                + "Your Age     : "+age+"\n"
                + "Your Address : "+address+"\n";
        jTextArea2.setText(data);
    }

    public void ClearData(){
        String kosong = "";
        jTextArea1.setText(kosong);
        jTextArea2.setText(kosong);
        jTextField1.setText(kosong);
        jTextField2.setText(kosong);
    }
```

**"LookData" JavaFORMClass**

```
    mainCode mainCode = new mainCode();

    String name;
    int age;
    String address;

    public LookData() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void getData(){
        name = mainCode.getName();
        age = mainCode.getAge();
        address = mainCode.getAddress();
    }

    public void printData(){
        String data = null;
        data =  "BIODATA REPORT\n"
                + "Your Name    : "+name+"\n"
                + "Your Age     : "+age+"\n"
                + "Your Address : "+address+"\n";
        jTextArea2.setText(data);
    }
```

## Conclusion

Maybe this problem is because I have to create and initialize the class like this

```
mainCode mainCode = new mainCode();
```

And because of this whenever I run the program the class will be reset to default and in form lookData the data will show null or zero.

I have realize this and tried

```
mainCode mainCode;
mainCode mainCode = code.mainCode();
String name = code.mainCode.name;
```

all of them give error

Anyone who knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

*I Tried in detail as I can, sorry if there is something wrong with this.*

Comment: I think you're basically on the right track.  What you need to do is make sure that both of your forms reference the *same* object.  You'll need a `new MainCode()` somewhere, but there should be just the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm think you are trying to lookup the saved record from the existing input data form, if the lookup pops when you press the "LOOK FROM ANOTHER FORM" button then, pass the mainCode obj to the constructor of the LookData. below is the way to do it

LookData Code:

```
    MainCode mainCode;

    String name;
    int age;
    String address;

    public LookData(MainCode main) {
        this.mainCode = main;
        initComponents();
    }

    public void getData(){
        name = mainCode.getName();
        age = mainCode.getAge();
        address = mainCode.getAddress();
    }

    public void printData(){
        String data = null;
        data =  "BIODATA REPORT\n"
                + "Your Name    : "+name+"\n"
                + "Your Age     : "+age+"\n"
                + "Your Address : "+address+"\n";
        jTextArea2.setText(data);
    }
```

Comment: I get the logic but I don't know how to do it. every example from the web is always for eclipse. I have tried to change lookData Code look like above. but there is error messege which say "java.lang.NullPointerException". maybe because I haven't pass the MainCode Objek into look Data when I klik  "LOOK FROM ANOTHER FORM" button. can u tell me how to pass MainCode objek from InputData JavaFormClass to LookData javaFormClass? thx.

Comment: sory and Thx my problem was solved, I just need to add this line "new LookData(mainCode).setVisible(true);" on those button.